# Have: Postgres database files. Need: Functioning database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, migration, postgresql-9.1

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with a postgres/postgis setup and in a weak moment removed PostgreSQL 9.1 (seemingly a legacy install from 12.04 from before I upgraded to 14.04), having erroneously convinced myself my current postgis setup relied on 9.3 alone.

That was not the case, and to make matters worse, I removed it while the instance was running, so I headed to the repositories to restore 9.1.

The repositories for Ubuntu don't have PostgreSQL 9.1 for 14.04, so I instead compiled from source so I could run pg_dump or pg_upgrade, which requires binaries from both.

But my issue then was that just because I now had a working version of 9.1 again, that didn't make my databases from earlier visible.

So, as far as I am aware, my database files are intact, but I need to 'hook' them up with the new 9.1 service I installed today. I hope it is trivial, but it has stumped me for hours. Any pointers for where to start with updating the config?

Comment: I don't know Ubuntu, but with a "vanilla" Postgres all you need to do is point `pg_ctl` to the right data directory, e.g. `pg_ctl -D /path/to/database/file start`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name on Ubuntu when using Pg from packages you should generally use `pg_wrapper` to manage Pg - `pg_ctlcluster`, `pg_createcluster`, etc. For hand-compiled it's like any other Pg.

Comment: Interesting, I see `postgresql-9.1` in my output of `apt-cache search postgresql`...

Comment: @dezso I I get this msg"--Package postgresql-9.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source." But I don't have the PGDG ppas added. That would probably have saved me some trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@a_horse_with_no_name is quite right. Because you compiled PostgreSQL from source, the usual tools provided by `pg_wrapper` like `pg_ctlcluster` and `pg_lsclusters` are not available. As a result the PostgreSQL init scripts on Ubuntu won't start your PostgreSQL 9.1 DB.

You could hook your custom binaries into `pg_wrapper`, but it's not worth the hassle for a one-off.

Assuming your 9.1 data directory is still owned by user `postgres` and in the default location:

- `sudo -u postgres -i`
- `PGPORT=5440 PATH=/path/to/your/9.1_install/bin pg_ctl -D /path/to/your/9.1/db`
- `PGPORT=5440 /path/to/9.3/bin/pg_dump -Fc -f mydb.pgdump mydb`
- `PGPORT=5440 /path/to/9.3/bin/pg_dumpall --globals-only > my_91_globals.sql`

then run `my_91_globals.sql` against your 9.3 server, or examine it and make any required changes.

Then `pg_restore` the `mydb.pgdump` using the `pg_restore` from 9.3.

You might need to adjust this if you're working from a restored backup copy of your 9.1 datadir, because its permissions may not be those of the `postgres` user. It does not matter what user owns it, but you might need to tweak `pg_hba.conf` if you're using `peer` auth and connecting as a different user.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach which should work for you is to install PostgreSQL from the PostgreSQL Global Development Group's APT repository.

They provide compiled versions of PostgreSQL for all supported versions of PostgreSQL and all supported versions of Ubuntu (and of course some versions of Debian).

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt is the starting point for this.